# An identity of complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k h_k(X)h_k(Y) t^{k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-polynomials

Let $p,q$ be integers, $X, Y$ two groups of different variables, $X=(x_1,\ldots,x_p)$ and $Y=(y_1,\ldots,y_q)$, and $h_r$ a complete homogeneous symmetric polynomials. Is there an identity analogue to Cauchy's identity, in the form:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty k h_k(X)h_k(Y) t^{k-1}? $$

Comment: If you replace $kt^{k-1}$ with $t^k$ Then it’s essentially the Cauchy identity. Then you can differentiate it in t

Comment: I think it is a bit different since the Cauchy identity holds when the sum is over all the partitions with $\ell(lambda)<n$ and is with $m_\lambda(X) h_\lambda(Y)$.

Comment: Possibly you’re right... then h_k is a series coefficient so this could be done with contour integrals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $h_k(X)=\frac1{2\pi I}\oint \frac{dz}{z^{k+1}}\prod_i\frac{1}{1-z x_i}$, similarly for $h_k(Y)$. Then the sum is

$$
\frac{1}{(2\pi i)^2}
\oint \oint \frac{wz\,dw dz}{(t-wz)^2}
\prod_{i}\frac{1}{1-z x_i}
\prod_{j}\frac{1}{1-w y_j}.
$$

The integration contours are around $0$ and are such that $|wz|>t$.

I am not sure how to further simplify this expression.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0} h_k(X)h_k(Y)t^k = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int
 \frac{1}{\prod_i(1-sx_it)\prod_j(1-y_j/s)}\frac{ds}{s}, $$
integrated around $|s|=1$, where $x_i$ and $y_j$ are small. It can be
shown by the Residue Theorem that this is equal (modulo computational
error) to
$$ \sum_j \frac{y_j^{q-1}}{\prod_i(1-x_iy_jt)\cdot \prod_{k\neq
 j}(y_j-y_k)}. $$
Now differentiate with respect to $t$. Not a very attractive answer,
but I doubt that one can do better. Note that it is not clear from this formula that it is invariant under interchanging the $X$-variables with the $Y$-variables.